# MOSFET model in LTspice with Miller Theorem

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, modeling

I want to make a MOSFET model in LTspice with a current source and the input capacities to see what happens in the switching process.

I'm not 100% sure but I think it works.

[image: First model resistive]

[image: Plots of first model]

Below is the formula I used in the current source. Here i said if `gm*(Vgs-Vt) < Id`, then it is in the active state.

```
I = if( (V(vg) < {Vth}), 1u, if( ({gm} x (V(vg)-{Vth}))-1m < (I(RL)+I(Cgd)), ({gm} x (V(vg)-{Vth})), V(vd)/{Rds}))
```

This is the inductive model:

[image: Inductive model]

[image]

That is the formula I used:

```
I = if( (V(vg1) < {Vth}), 0, if( V(vd1)-1m > (I(I1)+I(Cgd1)-I(DLL)) x {Rds}, ({gm} x (V(vg1)-{Vth})), V(vd1)/{Rds}))
```

Here I changed the conditions for the active state, but I think it should do the same. Active state is set when `Vd1 > Id1 x Rds`.

Are you think that it is right what I did? Does anyone have any suggestions for improvement?

I also tried to split the `cgd` capacitor with the Miller theorem. But that doesn't work at all. I've read that `cin = cgs + cgd(1+gm x RL)` and `gm x RL = Vd/Vgsmax` (in my case `Vd2/12V`). I put that in the capacitor `cmi2` (picture below) but it doesn't work. I have to say I would be surprised if it was that easy.

I'm also not sure if I need the capacitor `cmo2` and what to put in the equation for the current (the term `**Value**` below):

```
Id2 = if( (V(vg2) < {Vth}), 1u, if( V(vd2) < (I(R7)+**Value**) x {Rds}, ({gm} x (V(vg2)-{Vth})), V(vd2)/{Rds}))
```

Should it be the current of `Cmi2` or `Cmo2`?

And does anyone have any idea how I can get this to work?

[image: Mosfet with miller]

Comment: I'm heading off to bed soon, so I'll avoid (for now) any serious thoughts about your question. I'm assuming for now it's a good one and needs dedicated attention. I just don't have the time at this moment. But what you write does bring up something else that you may need to understand, if you want to get Spice to approximate reality with discrete MOSFETs (which I broadly dislike, except in certain cases where they really do excel over BJTs and really should be used instead.) So my next comment will highlight something else about Spice and MOSFETs. Keep it in mind. It's a problem. Just FYI.

Comment: MOSFET models in Spice use a Meyer capacitance model. Not charge storage conservation. Unfortunately, that model fails actual MOSFET behavior as it creates and destroys charge (which is wrong, as physics requires charge conservation.) This hasn't been fixed in Spice. Probably never will be, as there is no possible charge function possible that can be differentiated to generate the Meyer capacitance model. Can't be done. And Spice depends upon differentiation to get from A to B. So, some things will just be wrong -- especially with MOSFETs. Though you can get closer with small time steps.

Comment: Daniel, can you clarify this: do you mean to emulate a very basic MOSFET with a few discrete elements, or do you intend to build an actual model for the MOSFET? Because, if it's the former then you're well on your way with just what you have, so I'm not sure what you expect to "improve" it. If it's the latter then, obviously, you'll need a lot more elements in there, and it might get pretty numerically unstable if you insist on keeping `if()` and the likes.

Comment: @jonk  That is correct for Level 1, 2, and 3 models, but the BSIM models (Level 4, 5, 8, and 14 in LTspice) do use charge conservation.  Daniel would have to rewrite his own model though to include all the extra complexities.  Reference:  http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/external-documents/models/bsim330_manual.pdf

Comment: @SteKulov Thanks. I'll look into that when I get a moment. I am curious! Much appreciated!

Comment: thanks for your answers! @jonk and @a converned citizen, no i won't make an real mosfet model, it should be very simplified, i just want to show the main switching process with cgd and cgs involved. because of the improvemt - i meant, maybe i do something wrong in the formula of the current source. i thought, just because it looks right, doesn't mean i do it the right way.

Comment: If you're trying to emulate a discrete MOSFET, I would take a look at [the LTspice help page for MOSFET](https://www.ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/M_MOSFET.htm) and scroll down to where the Cgd of the VDMOS model is discussed.  It involves a mix of arc tangent and hyperbolic tangent functions.  Can also see DevCapVDMOS function in [ngspice code](https://sourceforge.net/p/ngspice/ngspice/ci/master/tree/src/spicelib/devices/devsup.c) for more info.

Comment: I want to ask a question. Why it need to **-1m** in the second if ? if( ({gm} x (V(vg)-{Vth})) **-1m** < (I(RL)+I(Cgd))

Comment: It's just a little hysteresis, I can't remember exactly, but either extremely short voltage jumps were otherwise visible or ltspice took too long to calculate. you can have the ltspice file from me if you want.